# How can I show my data in to table form using data table [FLUTTER]

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on a flutter where I have 2 Lists, 1. usersEmails, usersNames

How can I sort that code in a way that 1st element of userEmails and userNames become the 1st Row of data table.

Example:

1. List of Emails: [ABC, DEF, GHI]
2. List of Names: [MNO, PQR, XYZ]

**What I want is:**

**The Data Rows will depend on the total numbers elements in the Email/Name List.**

```
DataTable(
  columns: const [
    DataColumn(label: Text('ID'),),
    DataColumn(label: Text('Email'),),
    DataColumn(label: Text('Name'),),
  ],
  rows: const [
    DataRow(cells: [
      DataCell(Text("101")),
      DataCell(Text("ABC")),
      DataCell(Text("MNO")),
    ]),
    DataRow(cells: [
      DataCell(Text("102")),
      DataCell(Text("DEF")),
      DataCell(Text("PQR")),
    ]),
    DataRow(cells: [
      DataCell(Text("103")),
      DataCell(Text("GHI")),
      DataCell(Text("XYZ")),
    ]),
  ]
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try following code.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List lst =  ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI'];
  List lst2 =  ['asdas', 'adsasd', 'dfaas'];
  List<DataRow> generateDataRow(List ls) {
    List<DataRow> dataRows = [];
    //Both list should have same length
    //Otherwise it will throw errors.
    for (int i=0; i<ls.length; i++) {
      dataRows.add(
        DataRow(
          cells: [
            DataCell(Text(ls[i])),
            DataCell(Text(lst2[i])),
          ]
        )
      );
    }
    return dataRows;
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: DataTable2(
            columnSpacing: 12,
            horizontalMargin: 12,
            minWidth: 600,
            columns: const [
              DataColumn2(
                label: Text('Email'),
                size: ColumnSize.L,
              ),
              DataColumn(
                label: Text('Name'),
              ),
            ],
            rows: generateDataRow(lst),),
      ),// This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```